What does אַפּ֖וֹ mean?
So I'm trying to understand if anger is always sinful like many claim. A teacher i used to follow( I stopped out of him having very questionable approaches to certain aspects of scripture and other aspects of the Faith that border on cultlike dogmatism, I still keep in contact with him for certain questions taking them with a grain of salt, he's highly knowledgeable on context of passages often isolated to support doctrine as well ancient Greek and Hebrew) claims that "righteousness indignation" is not an idea found in Scripture. He goes on to claim that the mentions of God "getting angry" are anthropomorphism, basically using an idea we're familiar with and describing God as being that idea(or at the very least as that) to help us understand the consequences of defying Him.
Something that made me curious though was that in 1 Samuel 11:5, the Hebrew word אַפּ֖וֹ appears. I couldn't find what it translates to in English or a romanization to help with that either, but it's translated as "very angry". Other verses with this translate as "burning anger". This might be important because if you read the verse, it says the Holy Spirt(רֽוּחַ־ אֱלֹהִים֙, a Hebrew term for the Spirit) came upon him/filled him when this happened. He proceeded to act in a away that would seem like an angry thing to do before phrophesying as well.
I don't know Hebrew enough to tell if this was a cause and effect thing or if God just happened to speak through Saul then because it was the right time, but it is something to consider I think, even if אַפּ֖וֹ doesn't mean the type of anger/righteous indignation I'm thinking of. Does anyone know what this word means, and possibly if it's saying what I think in the verse?

See  https://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_samuel/11-6.htm  and  https://biblehub.com/hebrew/639.htm  It simply means nostril, nose, face, or anger.

Does the claim of "God's anger being an anthropomorphism" hold up?

God is often spoken about as being "angry" - in almost all cases, this would be an anthropomorphism.

So do you agree that anger is always a sin, or can you explain why some cases are actual anger?

Anger is not a sin, as it is possible to be angry and not sin simultaneously:  Eph 4:26 "Be ye angry, and sin not: let not the sun go down upon your wrath:"

It is possible to be angry and not sin as per Eph 4:26.  God gets angry with sin but does not sin, Rom 1:18, Eph 5:6, Col 3:6.  The big human problem with anger is the loss of personal control.

1 Samuel 11:5-7  involves a case of a human being becoming extremely angry as a result of God's spirit coming upon him.

5 Just then Saul came in from the field, behind his oxen. “Why are the
people weeping?” he asked. They repeated the message of the
inhabitants of Jabesh for him. 6 As he listened to this report, the
spirit of God rushed upon him and he became very angry. 7 Taking a
yoke of oxen, he cut them into pieces and sent them throughout the
territory of Israel by messengers saying, “If anyone does not come out
to follow Saul and Samuel, the same thing will be done to his oxen!”

The Bible is full of examples of God becoming angry, including ones where the word אַפּ֖וֹ - charon is used.  Strong's Concordance defines it as "a burning of anger -- sore displeasure, fierce(-ness), fury, (fierce) wrath(-ful)." Examples include:

Ex. 15:7  - In your great majesty you overthrew your adversaries; you loosed your wrath/anger to consume them like stubble.

Ex. 32: 12 - Why should the Egyptians speak, saying, ‘With evil intent He brought them out to kill them in the mountains and to destroy them from the face of the earth’? Turn from Your burning wrath/anger and change Your mind about doing harm to Your people.

1 Sam. 28:18 -As you did not obey the LORD and did not execute His fierce wrath/anger on Amalek, so the LORD has done this thing to you this day.

Jer. 49:37 I will terrify Elam before their foes,
those seeking their life; I will bring evil upon them,
my burning wrath/anger — oracle of the Lord.


Conclusion: It is beyond our scope here to opine as to whether God's anger is an anthropomorphism or not. Certainly, many modern critics believe so. As far as the text itself goes, God and humans both feel anger. The traditional theological explanation is that the difference between us is that God does not express his anger unjustly, but we often do.
